# VBA: const parameter for a Sub - avoiding modification of the value of an argument passed by value

Tags: vba, excel, arguments, constants

I mean to pass a parameter to a VBA `Sub`, ensuring that it is not modified. I would do that in C as `void mysub( const int i );`.

What is the recommended (i.e., simplest, most portable, etc.) way of achieving the same in VBA, if any?

**The question is about item 3 below. There is an accepted answer, but the question is open to alternatives (there is likely no last word on this).**

**EDIT**
Clarification of the equivalence in functionality VBA vs. C, needed as per answers and comments:

1. **Passing by reference**. 
   *In VBA*, `Sub mysub(i as Integer)` (the default, or `Sub mysub(ByRef i as Integer)`), which takes arguments by reference without "asking for permission" from the caller (who uses `Call mysub(j)`), has no exact equivalent in C.
   *In C*, the closest would be `void mysub(int * i);`. But in C one would have to complement this with a call as `mysub(&j);`, i.e., it is also up to the caller for this to work.
   The `Sub` can modify the value of "the variable" (`i`, in VBA; `*i`, in C) inside the called `Sub`. If it does, it automatically modifies the value in the caller.
2. **Passing by value**. 
   *In VBA*, `Sub mysub(ByVal i as Integer)`, which takes arguments by value from the caller (who uses `Call mysub(j)`, without even knowing whether `mysub` takes `ByVal` or `ByRef`), corresponds to 
   *In C*, `void mysub(int i);`. 
   The `Sub` can modify the value of "the variable" (`i`, in VBA or C) inside the called `Sub`. If it does, it does not affect the value in the caller.
3. **Passing by value, qualifying with `const`**. 
   *In C*, `void mysub(const int i);`. 
   The `Sub` cannot modify the value of "the variable" (`i`, in C) inside the called `Sub`. Of course, nothing happens to the value in the caller either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

VBA is not designed to prevent parameters from being modified inside of a function. If you want to do that, you have to implement those protections yourself as a workaround.  Below are two suggestions of how one might implement const protections in VBA.

The OP's final solution can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20193743/2832561).

---

**Protecting Parameters with Let and Get**

Here is an example of a way one might use to prevent a function from modifying the member variables of a class using Let and Get Properties.

Create a class clsPerson with the following code:

```
Option Explicit

Private m_strName As String
Private m_intAge As Integer
Private m_strAddress As String

Public LockMemberVariables As Boolean

Public Property Get Name() As String
    Name = m_strName
End Property

Public Property Let Name(strName As String)
    If Not LockMemberVariables Then
        m_strName = strName
    Else
        Err.Raise vbObjectError + 1, , "Member variables are locked!"
    End If
End Property

Public Property Get Age() As Integer
    Age = m_intAge
End Property

Public Property Let Age(intAge As Integer)
    If Not LockMemberVariables Then
        m_intAge = intAge
    Else
        Err.Raise vbObjectError + 1, , "Member variables are locked!"
    End If
End Property

Public Property Get Address() As String
    Address = m_strAddress
End Property

Public Property Let Address(strAddress As String)
    If Not LockMemberVariables Then
        m_strAddress = strAddress
    Else
        Err.Raise vbObjectError + 1, , "Member variables are locked!"
    End If
End Property
```

Create a normal code module with these functions:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub Main()
    Dim Bob As clsPerson
    Set Bob = New clsPerson

    Bob.Name = "Bob"
    Bob.Age = 30
    Bob.Address = "1234 Anwhere Street"

    Bob.LockMemberVariables = True

    PrintPerson Bob
    AlterPerson Bob

End Sub

Public Sub PrintPerson(p As clsPerson)
    MsgBox "Name: " & p.Name & vbCrLf & _
        "Age: " & p.Age & vbCrLf & _
        "Address: " & p.Address & vbCrLf
End Sub

Public Sub AlterPerson(p As clsPerson)
    p.Name = "Jim"
End Sub
```

Run the `Main()` function to test the clsPerson class.  This is a state-based runtime method to prevent a class' members from being modified that can be turned on and off.  Each Property Let in clsPerson checks to see if LockMemberVariables is true, and if so throws an error when an attempt is made to change its value. If you were to modify the code so that `Bob.LockMemberVariables = False` and then call AlterPerson, it would be able to modify the Name with no errors.

**Protecting Parameters with an Interface**

The other way you might implement protection is through interfaces.  In fact, you might prefer this since it works at compile-time.  Suppose you create an interface (class) called IProtectedPerson which *only supports Get for the member variables*:

```
Public Property Get Name() As String

End Property

Public Property Get Age() As Integer

End Property

Public Property Get Address() As String

End Property
```

Then you have your clsPerson class rewritten so that it has normal Let and Get, but also implements the IProtectedPerson interface:

```
Option Explicit

Implements IProtectedPerson

Private m_strName As String
Private m_intAge As Integer
Private m_strAddress As String

Public Property Get Name() As String
    Name = m_strName
End Property

Public Property Let Name(strName As String)
    m_strName = strName
End Property

Public Property Get Age() As Integer
    Age = m_intAge
End Property

Public Property Let Age(intAge As Integer)
    m_intAge = intAge
End Property

Public Property Get Address() As String
    Address = m_strAddress
End Property

Public Property Let Address(strAddress As String)
    m_strAddress = strAddress
End Property

'IProtectedPerson Interface Implementation

Private Property Get IProtectedPerson_Name() As String
    IProtectedPerson_Name = Me.Name
End Property

Private Property Get IProtectedPerson_Age() As Integer
    IProtectedPerson_Age = Me.Age
End Property

Private Property Get IProtectedPerson_Address() As String
    IProtectedPerson_Address = Me.Address
End Property
```

You would then create functions which take an IProtectedPerson as a parameter.  The code will fail to compile if you try to make an assignment to the private member variables because the Let functions aren't available on that interface:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub Main()
    Dim Bob As clsPerson
    Set Bob = New clsPerson

    Bob.Name = "Bob"
    Bob.Age = 30
    Bob.Address = "1234 Anwhere Street"

    AlterPerson Bob
    AlterProtectedPerson Bob
End Sub

Public Sub AlterPerson(p As clsPerson)
    p.Name = "Jim"
End Sub

Public Sub AlterProtectedPerson(p As IProtectedPerson)
    p.Name = "Sally"
End Sub
```

The code fails to compile because p in the `AlterProtectedPerson` function does not have a Property Let for Name.

Comment: @sancho.s I'll try to cook up a good couple examples for you as I have time and add them to the answer.  Now that I look at your question and comments, I think the best answer for you is "VBA is not designed to prevent parameters from being modified inside of a function.  If you want to do that, you have to implement those protections yourself as (probably somewhat ugly) runtime checks."

Comment: Sorry for the disgustingly long answer:S

Comment: @Blackhawk - I mean to accept your answer shortly. I propose: 1) For better readability, let us remove the comments that do not convey info on the topic. 2) I have added [a complementary answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20193743/2707864), I think that it would be useful for future readers that you hyperlink to it.

Comment: @sancho.s I removed the background info and kept just the short answer and the two examples.  I linked your answer as "The OP's final solution...".

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
Sub mysub(ByVal i As Integer)


End Sub
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa164263(v=office.10).aspx

**Important Text:**  When you define a procedure, you have two choices regarding how arguments are passed to it: by reference or by value. When a variable is passed to a procedure by reference, VBA actually passes the variable's address in memory to the procedure, which can then modify it directly. When execution returns to the calling procedure, the variable contains the modified value.
When an argument is passed by value, VBA passes a copy of the variable to the procedure. The procedure then modifies the copy, and the original value of the variable remains intact; when execution returns to the calling procedure, the variable contains the same value that it had before being passed..

**EDIT:**

I now understand you want to prevent the variable being modified in the called sub routine, not the caller sub.  Its not possible in the way you suggested.  VBA only has byval and byref for passing arguments.  You could try something like this (which is not full proof):

In a class module named: **ConstInteger**:

```
Private i As Variant
Public Property Get Value() As Integer
    Value = i
End Property
Public Property Let Value(Value As Integer)
    If IsEmpty(i) Then i = Value
End Property
```

Testing:

```
Sub Caller()
    Dim clsInt As New ConstInteger
    clsInt.Value = 1
    Call Called(clsInt)
End Sub
Sub Called(clsInt As ConstInteger)
    Debug.Print clsInt.Value
    clsInt.Value = 2
    Debug.Print clsInt.Value
End Sub
```

Comment: + 1 I guess this is what OP actually wants.

Comment: This is not what I was looking for. This prevents the caller sub from seeing any modification after the called sub is exited. My question referred to preventing modification within the called sub.

Comment: @Reafidy - the way the OP worded the question was fine. Value parameter semantics are clearly different from const ones.

Comment: @sancho, thanks for understanding.  Does Blackhawk's more in-depth answer below help you, or do you need further help?

Comment: @Reafidy - why the defensiveness? The original question clearly asked about C-style const parameters. Your answer wasn't terrible, it just missed the follow on point that VBA doesn't actually have true const parameters, or even something like the Pascal `const` or Java `final` (both of which suffer the limitation Blackwater mentions in the case of VBA's `ByVal` regarding reference types).

Comment: @sancho.s - you're not going to get any further - VBA has by reference and by value parameters, and that's it.

Comment: @Reafidy - I value the effort, but above all we should care about giving answers for the question in place. Please state from the outset that your proposal is not equivalent to what the question is about (It prevents the variable being modified in the called sub routine, not the caller sub. So it is equivalent to `void mysub( int i );`). Otherwise we risk being "perhaps dangerously incorrect" (the order of the statements is important).

Comment: @Reafidy - Let us clean the noise in comments, and only leave what conveys information on the topic. I have already cleared some.

Comment: @ChrisRolliston - Please let us clean the noise in comments, and only leave what conveys information on the topic. I have already cleared some. Thanks.

Comment: @Reafidy - I see by your edit that you have now acknowledged the point. Great! Not sure I would use the suggested workaround myself though - `const` (or `final`) in other languages can be a minor performance optimisation, yet instanting a new object and adding method calls just to imitate constant-ness is clearly the opposite.

Comment: @Reafidy - get a grip. In one sentence you assert my claim about performance (and complexity) is 'pointless'; in the next-but-one you concede it. The simple answer is that there is no 'solution' - VBA doesn't have constant parameters, and trying to fake it is a purely academic exercise.

Comment: @sancho I edited the question yesterday to provide you with an alternative solution, do you still have an issue?

Comment: @ChrisRolliston - I disagree in technical aspects. 1) "trying to fake it is a purely academic exercise": I wouldn't call code that is more fail-safe "a purely academic exercise" (and I guess that is the main reason for the existence of `const`). 2) "you're not going to get any further": it appears that one can go a little further, see [this excellent answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20132770/2707864).

Comment: @Reafidy - The solution you proposed does not work. Your definition of `Let` only checks if `Value` is empty, regardless of the scope. So you might be able to set the value in a scope where you want it to be `const`, and you might be denied setting the value in a scope where you want it to be not `const`. The proper way was given by @Blackhawk

Comment: @sancho.s - sometimes it is better just to accept that different languages have different features (e.g., C# doesn't have constant parameters either). That said, Blackwater's scenario (where you have an object you want to be immutable inside a function) is a plausible one I agree

Comment: @sancho, and you might be denied setting the value in a scope where you want it to be not const. Since when did this become a requirement? Your shifting the goal posts and are now expecting to choose if you want to pass the variable as a constant or not. Also, if using this code in an addin, the user would be able to change the constant value simply by changing the value of lockmembervariables to false. Which defeats the purpose of trying to pass a constant in the first place.

Comment: @Reafidy - 1) Regarding the question. The idea is coming up with a method for replicating `const` (as closely as possible, and noting the purportedly small number cases where it fails). Not being denied modifying the value outside the `const` scope is an evident part what is to be replicated (i.e., no need to specify it). There is no shifting of goal posts.

Comment: @Reafidy - 2) Regarding your proposal. It seems that I was not clear enough. Just invert the order of lines `clsInt.Value = 1` and `Call Called(clsInt)` in your Sub `Caller`. You will be able to change the value inside `Called`, and not inside `Caller`, exactly the opposite as required. And then `clsInt` will remain const for the rest of its life, regardless of scope. The point is that testing with `If IsEmpty(i) Then i = Value` in `Let Value` is arbitrary, possibly as much as with `If (i=4) Then i = Value`. Do you agree in that your proposal is off target?

Comment: @Reafidy - 3) Regarding the proposals by Blackhawk (one of them complemented by myself). The objective of having a (`Called`) `Sub` with a `const` parameter is to avoid modifying its value inside `Called`. Can you make a little more clear (perhaps with example/s, as I just gave) in what case/s would each one fail to attain the objective? This will improve our understanding. Thanks. PS: if you use the code I gave in `Sub called_const` in an addin, the user would not be able to change the `const` value; the `Sub` is already given (perhaps I misunderstood you).

Comment: @ChrisRolliston - I did not fully understand your comment. Do you think that the proposals by Blackhawk (one of them complemented by myself) have the required functionality? Can you identify in what case/s would each one fail to attain the objective? That is all what the question is about.

Comment: @sancho.s - the interface one is the way to go, and is in effect a standard pattern you might use in other languages too (Java, C#, Delphi, etc. - i.e., OOP languages where objects are reference types and interface types exist). Where I still don't things are worth it is if you are seeking to make a single integer parameter constant.

Comment: @sancho, 1) no I don't agree, you have missed the practicality in VBA with replicating a TRUE constant variable. Your original question was how to pass a constant variable to another sub, so I gave you an answer that involves a class object imitating a constant variable.  NOT a class object imitating either a constant variable OR a normal variable. Tell me how you can define `void Called(Const int i)` in C, and change the scope of the variable i in the Caller sub?

Comment: @sancho, 2) that would be a programming error, the same can be done with your boolean version. 3) No the sub is not given,  the caller sub is in the addin.  The called sub is end user defined.  The caller sub is trying to protect end user from modifying the variable.

Comment: You have had a mindset from the start about your question and have tried to bend the solutions towards it, evident by attempting to edit my answer and posting your own solution recommending blackhawk also adjust his to incorporate it.  I cannot help you further as we are on totally different wavelengths. Finally, given that you are the one asking the question on SO because you didn't know the answer, I found your comment that my solution was wrong and the proper way to it was blackhawks to be abrasive and in poor forum etiquette. But that's just my opinion.

Comment: @Reafidy - I was misunderstood (technically, and beyond). The question was always the same (it was not even edited!), and at least two other people understood it in the sense I meant, so it was clear from the get-go. Blackhawk gave an excellent detailed answer hitting the nail in the head (I simply added how the solution should be used), and Chris vouched for the answer.

Comment: @Reafidy - I did have a mindset from the start about the question: Get any answer that works for the objective proposed! As for interacting with answerers the way I did, I stand behind it, and I am satisfied with the result. I do not even care if I get no upvotes. My idea is to come up with the most useful SO for future readers as well; I see you think that brings undue "adjustments". And I did not mean to offend when pointing out that your proposal did not follow the question. I see no other way of using SO for the best of all of us. I meant to be respectful at all times. My apologies.

Comment: @sancho, Your requirements changed as per your comments, I never said you edited the question that's irrelevant.  I don't believe it was _clear from the get go_.  Sidd posted a solution and later deleted it because it was not what he thought you were asking.  If you want to talk numbers, I would say the 5 people that up-voted my answer also thought the same way as me, and figured that's what you were asking, but whatever.  I accept your apology regarding etiquette.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is based on [another excellent answer to this question, here called BH](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20132770/2707864).

A subsititute for `const` as in **Protecting Parameters with Let and Get** ([search in the answer BH](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20132770/2707864)) should be used as follows.
Within a function that is meant to work as `called_const(const clsInt As clsPerson)` (following the example in answer BH), one would add

```
Sub called_const(clsInt As clsPerson)
    clsInt.LockMemberVariables = True
    <Functionality of the Sub>
    clsInt.LockMemberVariables = False
End Sub
```

Then, if there is some code in `called_const` that goes against the `const` prescription, it will generate a runtime error (instead of the compile error for the case of C).
I can think of one (possibly uncommon) case where this would fail. When another similar `Sub` (say, `called_const2(const clsInt As clsPerson)`) is called from `called_const`. Then, the unlocking performed at the end of `called_const2` would be effective for the remainder of `called_const` as well.

A subsititute for `const` as in **Protecting Parameters with an Interface** ([search in the answer BH](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20132770/2707864)) appears to work exactly as intended.

**Conclusion**

There seem to be possible ways of imitating `const` behavior. The cost is having to write extra code, and define new class(es) for each `const` type one wants to use.

PS: What about the case where some members of `const` objects are in turn other objects?